# Cannot invoke initializer for type: with an argument list of type '(_Element)'

Tags: swift, swift2

I am new on Swift. I am trying to convert string to character array and I want the integer value of character. Here is my code:

```
var string = "1234"
var temp  = Array(string.characters)
var o = Int(temp[0])
```

But at line 3 I am getting above error. What's wrong with this code?
Please help me

Comment: Thanks for helping me Can u pls post this comment as a answer so that  Ican upvote it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to map your Character to String because Int has no Character initializer.
You can also map your Character array to String Array

```
var temp  = string.characters.map(String.init)
```

or convert your character to String when initializing your var

```
var o = Int(String(temp[0]))
```

**Swift 4**

```
let string = "1234"
let temp  = string.map(String.init)
let o = Int(temp[0])
```